# javascript for splitting url and removing last part

Tags: javascript, jquery, .net

http://www.google.com/site!#656126.72367

In this url, how to split and remove the part from exclamatory mark when page loaded using JS.

I just want http://www.google.com/site

Comment: do u mean string replace??

Comment: Don't forget to accept the right answer @Saichand

Answer (score 2):

You could use:

```
var host = window.location.hostname; // will be www.google.com
var path = window.location.pathname; // will be /site
```

In the end, you will have:

```
var url = "http://" + host + path;
```

Note: you can also use `window.location.protocol`, which in this case is `http:`:

```
var url = window.location.protocol + '//' + host + path;
```

Update: as suggested by [Rajesh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3783478/rajesh), the `window.location` object also has access to the hash:

```
var hash = window.location.hash; // will be 656126.72367
```

It might be useful to do a `console.log(window.location)` and see what's in there!

---

This method works even if the hash contains several `!` or `#`

Comment: Also mention `location.hash`.

Answer (score 2):

```
var url = 'http://www.google.com/site!#656126.72367';
url = url.substring(0, url.indexOf('!'));
document.write(url);
```

substring extracts the characters from a string, between two specified indices (in this case on the first occurence and then on `!`), and returns the new sub string.

[jsFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/mL2sso4u/)

Answer (score 2):

Use string `replace` method , match every character after `!` with regular expression and replace with `""`

```
var url = 'http://www.google.com/site!#656126.72367';
    url =  url.replace(/!.*/,"");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var url = "http://www.google.com/site!#656126.72367";
url = url.split('!')[0];
console.log(url);
```